# Облачные хранилища для хранения контента приложений

Tags: parse.com, облачное-хранилище

Пишу приложение для Ios. Пользователи по мере выхода контента для приложения (музыка, фото) должны иметь возможность скачивать его.  
Кто нибудь знает облачные хранилища, где можно хранить, добавлять контент? 
Я пробовал Яндекс Диск, но он, как оказалось, не предназначен для того, чтобы с одного диска скачивали многие пользователи.  
Еще пробовал Parse.com, но у меня есть возможность взаимодействовать с сервером  только через REST API, а в этом сервисе скачивать файлы можно только, имея опреленный sdk.
Можете посоветовать удобный сервис для этой задачи?

**Обновление**

Может быть, Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) или Google Cloud Storage?

Оставил свой выбор на Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3).

Comment: По поводу Parse.com: можно сделать свою функцию в Cloud Code, которая будет возвращать URL файла. Для этого потребуется написать несколько строк кода на JS.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле в Яндекс Диске вы можете опубликовать файл и раздавать ссылку на этот файл своим пользователям.